# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered (in visual studio 2013_ win 8_ microsoft access 2013 x64)

Tags: c#

I use Visual studio 2013 and I have win8 X64, I upgraded my access 2003 x32 database to access 2013 and when I tried to connect to my access 2013 X64 database,I have got this error:

```
error message:
```

> The'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine.

I installed  the `AccessDatabaseEngine_x64` but its not still working.

Answer (score 1):

finally i found the answer.
I installed "2007 Office System Driver Data Connectivity Components" from below link:

> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

And it worked without any problem.